# Should I peel kiwifruit?

Tags: food-safety, peeling, kiwifruit

What should I do with the kiwi peel? 
I've got no problem with its taste and feel 
and eat them whole when I'm by myself. 
Is it in any way bad for my health?

Comment: My grandmother cuts them in halves and eat the pulp out of the skin with a spoon. Just a tip.

Comment: @Johnny: That's what I used to do, but lately I've been too lazy to go to the kitchen for a knife and spoon.

Comment: @Johnny: I use a grapefruit spoon, works even better!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to eat the peel in and of itself. You will need to make sure that you wash it properly, as it may be dirty. But beyond that, it's simply a matter of taste. A lot of people don't like the flavor / texture of the peel and so remove it.

From a [site devoted to kiwis](http://kiwi-fruit.info/):

> Kiwi fruit skin is definitely edible,
>   and there's a lot of different
>   theories about eating it.
>
> Kiwi fruit skin contains high levels
>   of flavonoids, insoluble fiber and
>   antioxidants: these substances all
>   have a beneficial effect on your
>   body's metabolic functions (flavonoids
>   and antioxidants) and on your
>   digestive system and cardiovascular
>   apparatus (insoluble fiber).
>
> Common sense, however, should be
>   practiced in this respect: while raw
>   kiwi fruit skin contains these
>   beneficial substances, it also tends
>   to contain more than 99,95% of of the
>   pesticides in that particular fruit
>   (if they have been used), which
>   largely outweighs the benefits from
>   flavonoids and antioxidants.

Comment: According to your quote, eating the peel would result in eating 2 000 times more pesticides. Perfectly safe?

Comment: perfectly safe "in and of itself", yes.  It's only IF the kiwifruit you are eating has been treated by pesticides that you may choose to weigh up the pros and cons of ingesting the pesticides.

Comment: Sounds like a case where buying trusted organic is well worth it.

Comment: Also, washing fruit tends to remove a large amount of pesticides, at least on smooth skin like apples. It might be a little trickier for a hairy skin like a kiwi.

Comment: @Kimba, @Tim: Seems to me it's the absolute quantity we should care about. It's all well and good to say it's 2000 times worse than the flesh, but does that bring it to an unsafe level or not?

Comment: @Tim, yes, I meant that the skin of the fruit didn't have any inherent danger, but that if it was dirty (pesticides would be included in that), then it should be washed or removed.

Comment: I doubt if much if any pesticides would be left after a few rainfalls. And Kiwifruit are generally not treated with pesticide during the latter part of their growing cycle. Most are basically organic

Comment: @Everyone: Thank you for giving me enough information to make an educated choice.

Comment: @TimN: you realize that "2000 times more pesticides" does not mean anything, right? You have to consider absolute doses, type of pesticides, and frequency of ingestion for that to be meaningful.

Answer (score 9):

In New Zealand the export Kiwifruit brand is called Zespri. The have fully organic and close to organic orchards. Most of the spraying happens early in the growing cycle, so by the time you buy it it has been rain washed many times. I have family friends whom have export large Kiwifruit orchards and it is a very organic process once the fruit has formed

See http://www.zespri.com/sustainability-home/growing-zespri-on-orchard/kiwigreen.html

The green Kiwifruit is very fuzzy and not nice to eat, the gold Kiwifruit is designed to be eaten skin and all. Kiwi Grapes (bunches of baby Kiwifruit) are also designed to be eaten skin and all

Kiwifruit in New Zealand is considered a scoop fruit though (same as tamarillos, fejoas etc), and you don't see many locals eating the skin

The good part of the skin (Exocarp) is not just the dry outer layer, it is the thin living layer immediately behind that. You'll eat that by scooping the fruit out, not so much by cutting it out

For serving speed we normally cut of the ends, halve, and then place half cut down and slice off the skin working around fruit. Then slice into small discs and serve

[image: Sliced kiwifruit]

During picking season the huge surpluses are feed to the beef cows skin and all :-)

Comment: So NZ-ers usually eat whole kiwifruits? It's nice to know that it's a common practice.

Comment: Ummn, no. As I said "you don't see many locals eating the skin". Sliced or scooped is the norm. We can't generally afford the Gold or Grape varieties, we export them all :-)

Comment: Mmmmm, grape kiwifruit. And you've got me pining for feijoas! Hurry up, autumn!

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to "the gold Kiwifruit is designed to be eaten skin and all". Should have read a little more carefully. But then again, how come natives don't eat the skin if it's supposed to be eaten?

Comment: We can't generally afford the Gold varieties, they are the skin edible type. The green variety skin is not good for eating (too furry). I guess we are just used to peeling them all because of this

Comment: The golds are designed to be eaten with skin! Learn something new everyday, I thought they where just.. well... yellow...

Comment: @Layna This post is 4 years old. A lot has happened since then. Many Kiwifruit farmers have now suffered from a disease that kills the old Gold variety to which this post refers too. The new Gold variety they are growing is not so great in the skin department, better than Green, but a bit fuzzy for my taste

Answer (score 3):

Kiwi fruit skin is definitely edible.

But I would suggest to soak the fruit in water for a while to wash it properly and so that all the pesticides been may get washed off nicely…
I only like to eat the skin of gold kiwi as its hairless and hate the hairy texture of green..:)

Comment: Hello Mandy, and welcome to Seasoned advice! Nutrition is off topic on our site, so I removed the sentence praising the healthiness of kiwi skin and left the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I dip the kiwifruit in boiling water for a minute or so then eat the whole thing.  The dip softens the skin a little, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thoroughly washing and eating kiwifruit for over 20 years and find the skins vary in texture and flavour if both are good I eat them

Answer (score 1):

I love the skins and always eat them.  Though, from now on, I'll give them an extra wash. I know lots of people who eat the skin!

Comment: Quoting someone here----"But then again, how come natives don't eat the skin if it's supposed to be eaten?" ---- we nzers DO often eat the skins !!!

Answer (score 1):

Kiwis are #10 on the EWG Clean 15 List, so not a big pesticide problem

Answer (score -1):

Up to now I have been eating golden skin after thorough washing with warm water. Although without skin the inner flesh is far tastier.